# Private Route with React and Axios.get

Tags: reactjs, axios

Im trying to make a private route where if im not logged in, it will redirect to log in, if not then it will bring me to home but I'm struggling on making it work

my privateRoute.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import Axios from 'axios'
import Home from "./home/home.js"

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {

    Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    useEffect(()=> {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/login").then((response) => {
            if (response.data.loggedIn === true) {
                console.log("HOME")
                return (
                    <>
                        <Home/>
                    </>
                )
                
            } else {
                navigate("/" , {replace: true})
            }
        })
    },[])
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

my App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom"

// COMPONENTS
import Login from './login/login.js'
import Home from './home/home.js'
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute.js'

// STYLE
import './login/login.css'
import './register/register.css'
import './App.css'


const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Login/>}></Route>
            
                <Route exact path="/home" element={
                    <PrivateRoute>
                        <Home/>
                    </PrivateRoute>

                }></Route>
            </Routes>
        </>
    )
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import Axios from 'axios'
import Home from "./home/home.js"

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {

    Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    useEffect(()=> {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/login").then((response) => {
            if (response.data.loggedIn === true) {
                setLoggedIn(true);
            } else {
                navigate("/" , {replace: true})
            }
        })
    },[])

    if (!loggedIn) {
        return (
            <>
                Loading...
            </>
        )
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Home/>
            // Or {...children}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you so much bro ive been trying to figure out this whole day :D

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to return a `ReactNode` from with a `useEffect`.

The `return` of a `useEffect` is used as a clean up function to be run on component unmount or before the next execution of the `useEffect`.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // set a timer to show an alert in 20 seconds.
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => alert('I\'m a cool kid!'), 20000);

    return () => {
        // clear the timer if the component is unmounted so that the 
        // alert will no longer trigger
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
}, [])
```

To fix your issue your `PrivateRoute` component will need to return what you want it to render:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import Axios from 'axios'
import Home from "./home/home.js"

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
    // state to store whether the auth check has completed.
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    // state to store whether the user is authenticated
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

    // state to store any error encounted while running the auth check.
    const [error, setError] = useState();

    Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(()=> {
        // create async function to avoid the use of promise .then spam
        // this is just a preference coming from C# background prefer the 
        // async / await syntax.
        const checkLogin = async () => {
            try {
                // run the auth check.
                const response = await Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/login");
    
                // set whether the user is logged in.
                setLoggedIn(!!response?.data?.loggedIn)

                // set that no error was encountered.
                setError(undefined);

                // start redirection if not logged in.
                if (!response?.data?.loggedIn) {
                    navigate("/" , {replace: true});
                }
            }
            // catch any error with the request.
            catch (err) {
                // set user to not logged in.
                setLoggedIn(false);

                // set the error to the caught exception.
                setError(err);

                // add another redirect call if you don't want to display an error when the request fails
                // e.g.: navigate("/" , {replace: true});
            }

            // request is finished set loading to false.
            setLoading(false);
        };

        checkLogin();
    }, [setLoading, setError, setLoggedIn])

    // This is the view while the auth check is being carried out:
    if (loading) {
        return (
            <>
                I am checking auth status...
            </>
        );
    }

    // This is the view if the auth check encounters an error:
    if (error) {
        return (
            <pre>
                {JSON.stringify(error, null, '\t')}
            </pre>
        );
    }

    // This is the view if the user was not authenticated
    // As the redirect is started as part of the useEffect this will
    // most likely not be displayed for any significant (or even preceivable)
    // amount of time.
    if (!loggedIn) {
        return (
            <>
                I am redirecting...
            </>
        );
    }

    // This is the view if the user was authenticated.
    // Example view below renders the child elements that have been provided i.e. <Home /> in your snippet.
    return (
        <>
            {children}
        </>
    )
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

Comment: Thanks for this clear detailed explanation sir! It helped me understand it much better now